# order eloquent result by string value in child table

Tags: php, laravel

```
 DB::table('cases')
        ->select('cases.*',DB::raw('courts.*'))
        ->leftjoin('Courts', 'cases.court_id', '=', 'Courts.id')
        ->orderByRaw("FIELD(court, 'supreme court','high court','area court')")
        ->get();
```

The result of the above query is order by the string value of the court column in the courts table. Please how can this be done using eloquent query. I have tried

**Controller**

```
 return Cases::with('courts')
          ->orderby(
           
            Courts::select('court')
            ->whereColumn('id','cases.court_id')
            ->orderByRaw("FIELD(court, 'high court','supreme court','area court')")
            ->limit(1)
        )
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constrain how the eager laoded model's query is done, the documentation gives you a good example [Eloquent Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```php
return Cases::query()
    ->with(['courts' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('court', 'court_id')
            ->orderByRaw("FIELD(court, 'high court', 'supreme court', 'area court')");
    }])
    ->get();
```

A few limits:

- You **need** to include the foreign column (`court_id`) in your select clause, because this is how Eloquent will figure out how to associate each `Court` model with its corresponding `Cases` .
- You cannot use `LIMIT` in the query constraint, as this will have an effect on every eager loaded `Court` model instead of just the ones associated with each particular `Cases`.